# is it possible to implement query rewrite & materialized view in generated OBIEE query

Tags: data-warehouse, obiee, materialized-views

I have read a paper about [materialized view selection in datawarehouse](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Navaneetham_P_Dr/publication/50235135_A_Framework_for_the_View_Selection_Problem_in_Data_Warehousing_Environment/links/565532f908aefe619b1a5108.pdf) , and I have been trying to implement it in OBIEE, but the generated query from OBIEE are start using WITH Clause / CTE / Subquery factoring.

---

This query are not rewrited to materialized view as I expected, and its a similiar issue in [this oracle community forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4113724) , but query rewrite work only when I create materialize view in base table on **where clause** as discussed in the paper above , but our generated obiee query use an extremely complex subquery factoring, then this won't make a significant increase in query speed.

I just want to know is it possible to implement query rewrite & materialized view in generated OBIEE query in terms of the discussion in the paper above ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Longer answer: No, because that's not how the product is built. It's meant to be a source-agnostic query generator and analytics platform, not a programming platform to let you develop queries on your own. You need to understand how the product works, hoe IT optimizes queries and chooses its sources. There are literally dozens of ways to influence how your query is getting written but they are all semantic/structural configuration options. You do not write code in OBI.